# cast retrieved object from localstorage with TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

`const [history, setHistory] = useState(localStorage.getItem('history') || {});`

TS doesn't know what's the history type anymore once I've saved it in the localstorage and retrieve it back, how do I reassign the type back? so that I can use it like

`JSON.parse(history).id`

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code? What is `localStorageGet`, and where do you need to "reassign the type back"?

Comment: What type does `localStorageGet` return?

Comment: @zerkms history from localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `localStorage.getItem` returns either a string or null - you can't really inject the type of the string after it gets JSON-parsed without a type cast / type assertion afterwards.

I'd make a wrapper around `localStorage.getItem` which parses the string in `localStorage` and returns an object of the correct type:

```
const getHistory = () => {
    const json = localStorage.getItem('x') ?? '{}';
    return JSON.parse(json) as { id?: number };
    // replace number type above with whatever is needed
};
// ...

// Retrieve initial history only once, not on every render:
const initialHistory = getHistory();
const App = () => {
    const [history, setHistory] = useState(initialHistory);
```

Note that with this approach, the `history` variable is the *typed object*, not a string (which is probably desirable - it'll be easier to work with).